# Wordpress login using a completely custom page and no plugins?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to achieve having a completely custom WordPress login page, using a project from codepen. It's just html and css at the moment with input fields that don't really do anything, is there a way to turn it into a functional login system that isn't overly complicated?

Comment: Did you read everything here? https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form .

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to do a bit of coding, then start by creating a new  page template for your login page, name a file something like `page-login.php` in your themes root and make that page markup how you want it.

Once you have the mark-up in place, add in the following tag, which will pull in the WP login form onto the page for you.

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" class="btn secondary">Forgotten Password?</a>
```

If it's the markup of the form itself that you want to change, I don't believe you can. But, doing the above will give you the facility to add custom styling, CSS, JS, to the page if required.